# Add a new subscriber role using a function

Tags: functions, user-roles

Is it possible to add a new subscriber role with a function, that has the same capabilities with the existing subscriber role within Wordpress?

Basically I would like to distinguish between male and female subscribers based on the wordpress role.

Comment: Do you want to add a new role for each user, or create custom roles that you assign to user ?

Comment: I want to create a new role that I can assign to users. e.g. "Male Subscriber", "Female Subscriber"

Comment: What you're looking for is here ! https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role :)

Comment: you could also do this with user meta

Comment: thanks but the explanation on the codex page is a bit confusing and talks about creating a custom plugin. I was wondering if there is an easier way with a function.

Answer (score 4):

A subscriber has only 1 capability namely: read
To create a new (custom)role just add following code-lines in `functions.php`.

> Please make back-up first and so on....

When added to `functions.php` go into the back-end and check if you can add an (new or existing) user to this role.
When all is working you can delete the code because the roles are now added to the database and there is no need to keep them.

```
/**
 * Create new custom role(s)
 * 
 * Subscriber capability set: read
 * 
 * Source {@link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/306353/15605}
 * @see   {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/add_role}
 * @see   {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities}
 *
 * @version  WordPress 4.9.6
 * 
 */
    // Adjust to your own preferences.
    // Subscr_F and M are visible in you back-end, but you can adjust all.
    add_role( 'subscr_female', __( 'Subscr_F' ), array( 'read' => true ) );
    add_role( 'subscr_male',   __( 'Subscr_M' ), array( 'read' => true ) );
```

I hope this is what you where looking for.